# What is the time complexity of removing among $N$ sets of size at most $n$ the sets which are subsets of another set?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sets

A naïve solution would be to first sort all sets, taking time $O(N n \log n)$. Then, for every possible pair of sets, check if one is a subset of the other, and if applicable remove the subset. This checking and removing can all be done in time $O(N^2 n)$. The total time complexity would thus be $O(N n \log n + N^2 n)$, which if $N = \Theta(n)$ would be $O(n^3)$.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you add more details on what you mean by "are included in others"? For example, if $S_1 = \{1, 2\}$, $S_2 = \{1, 3\}$ and $S_3 = \{2, 3\}$, then each set is included in the union of the two others. Do you want to remove all three of them?

Comment: In this case I would want to keep all three sets. I only want to remove a set if it is included in another set. I'll reword it this way.

Comment: Exactly, isn't this commonly meant by "a set included in another"?

Comment: @PålGD no assumptions are made on the sets.

Answer (score -1):

By [Cunningham's law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law), this is the best possible time complexity.